# Is there a way to copy/paste keyframes to a extrapolation cycle?

Tags: animation

I want to make all the keyframes appear like this [image]

instead of the blank cycle like this [image]

Is there a way? I want this because sometimes I need to make change on the cycle and without keyframes, a single new keyframe will ruin the cycle. I really dont want to copy/paste all keyframes on the dopesheet because everything will be a mess and will take too much time!
thanks

Comment: Is your intention to make a modification that affects all the cycles, or only deviate for a single event with future cycles unchanged?

Comment: For example lets say I have an arm cycle animation. At some point I want to change a single rotation keyframe of that cycle, but let the cycle continue. If I had the keyframes there instead of a blank cycle, I could just select that particular key and change it without having to worry about the cycle being ruined.

Answer (score 2):

A manual process would be to use the Graph Editor.

- Remove the Cycles modifier
- select all keyframes
- copy the keyframes : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
- navigate to the last keyframe : <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>up</kbd> then (plain) <kbd>down</kbd>
- paste keyframes : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>

Repeat those last two steps until you have filled the timeline.

It would be possible to clone the keyframes via python, but unless you need 20+ copies, the manual process should be adequate.  (let me know if the python is required)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with F-Curve cycles modifier. The F-Curve modifier panel is located in the Properties region in the Graph Editor.

To add a modifier, select the curve you want to add cycles to, select Modifiers tab in the properties region, click on **Add Modifier** and select **Cycles**.

[image]

Comment: Tried that but that doesnt add the keyframes like I wanted.